# Drawing meteorological maps in python

Tags: python, django

I found a user friendly way plotiing meteorological maps with python. I found this flight path tool, http://www.aviationweather.gov/flightpath2?gis=off , and i want to make something like this in python. I have made the scripts retrieving the data and plotting the maps but i want to make the interface. Is it difficult? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to make a web-based interface? If so, I suggest maybe Django. If you want just a script with some nice GUI on a local machine, I think Qt is easy to use. I can't run the java file from aviationweather.gov (or rather, do not wish to) so I don't know what the interface is like. But using either Django or Qt, I think those are the tools I would start with.

Comment: Could you help me how could i start for a web interface with Django? I know it but never used it. It nedds a lot of time to made it?? The same with Qt

Answer (score 0):

Check out the video here.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/03/22/introducing-r-tools-for-visual-studio-3/

Start watching about 7 minutes into the video.  I think that will be a great learning experience for you, and should get you going in the right direction.